# Passing touch events to uiimageview within a scrollview added as subview to view

Tags: iphone, scrollview

I have added one scrollview and imageview to my view. When I touch on this imageview my scrollview scrolls. And within my scrollview there are lots of imageviews which have touch events written separately.

Here is the view hierarchy

```
                          View
                            |
                            |
                    -------   --------
                   |                  |
                imageView1         scrollview
                                       |
                                  ...........................
                                  |           |       |.....|
                                 imageviews2
```

Imageview1 is above imagesview2 in appearance.

And when I scroll the scrollview it is not possible to touch some of the imageViews within the scrollview as it comes behind the imageview within view.

**How can I pass the touch events to the imageviews2 whenever it is behind imageview1.**

Comment: `setUserInteractionEnabled:NO` for `imageView1` ?

Comment: I am sorry its not possible to do as you instructed because I have to scroll when the user touches the scrollview. If I do this then that feature cannot be added.

Comment: if you disable userInteraction on the imageView1, scrolling on the `UIScrollView` will still be enabled...

Comment: I tried this and my scrollview stopped scrolling after this when i touch on imageView1 :(

Comment: Can you show us the code you used?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to subclass `UIView` and override

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

in that subclass to skip imageView1.

You might get away with subclassing `UIImageView` and instantiating imageView1 as a member of that class, and overriding pointInside

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ return NO; }
```

Comment: Can you please explain it in a broad way with an example or something?

Answer (score 0):

don't forget also to uncheck "delays content touches" and "cancellable content touches" on your scrollview !

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer might be useful for someone. I have done it without using hittest.

Took all the subviews in scrollview and checked if it is an image view and did the following.

Passed the touchevents to another view using [view touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; we have to write the same in touchesMoved and touchesEnded also.

Thanks,

Joku

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the touch event to the UIViews that are outside the bounds of the parent view.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    // Convert the point to the target view's coordinate system.
    // The target view isn't necessarily the immediate subview
    CGPoint pointForTargetView = [self.targetView convertPoint:point fromView:self];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.targetView.bounds, pointForTargetView)) {

        // The target view may have its view hierarchy,
        // so call its hitTest method to return the right hit-test view
        return [self.targetView hitTest:pointForTargetView withEvent:event];
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa2013/qa1812.html